# JavaScript / jQuery only works on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I'm developing a little site that loads a local HTML file into an `iframe` on click of a button. The iframe should be resized based on the size of the content of the local HTML file. The following almost works -- however, I need to click the "Fill" button **twice** in order to resize the iframe (Firefox).

I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with how events are being handled, but I've tried `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` without any luck. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Load</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#run").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var framex = document.getElementById('iframe');
                framex.setAttribute("src", "local.html");
                framex.style.height = (framex.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 50) + "px";
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="run" type="button" value="Load">
    <div id="div" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; overflow: auto;">
        <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" frameBorder="0">

        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time you are assigning `framex.style.height`, the page was not loaded yet, so the document has no size (or does not even exist, which would result in an error then).

You have to wait until the page was loaded:

```
framex.onload = function() {
    this.style.height = (this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 50) + "px";
};
```

Comment: In other words, setting the `src` of the `iframe` does not mean that the document (and its dependencies, e.g. CSS) will have already loaded by the time execution moves on to the next line.